# Check for file by wildcard and store as variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a way to check a specified folder for a file. I will not have the complete file name, so I will have to use wildcards.  After finding the file, I want to store the filename as a variable.

Comment: Is [_Batch script, check if file exists, then execute_](http://serverfault.com/questions/819854/batch-script-check-if-file-exists-then-execute) the same question? Ask rather at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file).

Answer (score 11):

Doesn't directly answer your question about a batch file but this would work easily in a PowerShell script:

```
$validFile = Test-Path "C:\path\to\your\file"
if ($validFile -eq 'True') {
    $path = C:\path\to\your\file
}
```

And now you have your file name stored in a variable

Answer (score 10):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set LIST=
for %%x in (%baseDir%\*) do set LIST=!LIST! %%x
set LIST=%LIST:~1%
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not very useful. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does.